# SQL combine tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follow:

Table1:

```
f1      f2
1        2
3        4
5        6
7        8
```

Table2:

```
f1      f3    f4
 1       R    20
 1       m    10
 1       m    30
 3       m    5
 5       R    20
```

So now I need a table like:

```
f1      f2      SUM(f4 where f3=m)
1       2           40
3       4           5
5       6           null
7       8           null
```

In other word if the f1 exist in table2 and f3='m' then get the sum of it otherwise just select all the data from table1.

I tried the following codes:

```
SELECT T1.* , T2.SUM(f4)
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.f1 = T2.f1
WHERE T2.f3='m'
```

This only shows the one exist in the Table2 and if I do:

```
SELECT T1.* , T2.SUM(f4)
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.f1 = T2.f1 AND T2.f3='m'
```

Shows 20 for f3, 5 and 60 for 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  T1.f1 ,
        T1.f2 ,
        T2.SUM(f4)
FROM    Table1 AS T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 
        ON T1.f1 = T2.f1
        AND T2.f3 = 'm'
GROUP BY T1.f1 ,
         T1.f2
```

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax of your group by clause?

Comment: Nope, my bad. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.F1, T1.F2, sum(T2.f4)
from Table1 T1
left outer join  Table2 as T2
on (T1.F1 = T2.F1 and T2.F3 = 'm')
group by T1.F1 , T1.F2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     dbo.tab1.f1, dbo.tab1.f2, CASE WHEN f3 = 'm' THEN SUM(f4) ELSE NULL END AS    Expr1
FROM       dbo.tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN        
           dbo.tab2 ON dbo.tab1.f1 = dbo.tab2.f1 AND dbo.tab2.f3 = 'm'
GROUP BY   dbo.tab1.f1, dbo.tab1.f2, dbo.tab2.f3
```